# Add a new column indicating whether the next row has the same value in a certain column or not

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe of US congress members, that looks like this:

| name | session |
| --- | --- |
| Sen Tom | 115 |
| Sen Tom | 116 |
| Sen Tom | 117 |
| Sen Jack | 115 |
| Sen Jill | 116 |
| Sen Jill | 117 |
| Sen Dave | 116 |
| Sen Dave | 117 |

I want to create a new variable that tells me whether each politician successfully retained their seat in the next legislative session. I want to create this variable using the session column. In my data, if the politician with a given name has a session value greater than the current, it means they did retain their seat. If there are no more higher sessions, they didn't retain their seat. For example, for the first row of Sen Tom, I would want to use the "115" value and they have it look to see if Sen Tom has a value in the session column greater than "115". If he does, the new column would show a yes or 1. If there aren't any values for Sen Tom greater than "115", it means he didn't retain his seat in the next election, and so it would be a "no" or a 0. In the table below, you can get an idea of what I want the output to look like.

| name | session | retained seat? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sen Tom | 115 | 1 |
| Sen Tom | 116 | 1 |
| Sen Tom | 117 | 0 |
| Sen Jack | 115 | 0 |
| Sen Jill | 116 | 1 |
| Sen Jill | 117 | 0 |
| Sen Dave | 116 | 1 |
| Sen Dave | 117 | 0 |

I'm assuming there is an easy way to accomplish this, but I can't figure it out. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ```library(data.table); setDT(df1)[,`retained seat?` := as.integer(max(session) > session), .(name)][]```

Answer (score 1):

in base R:

```
transform(df, retained = +(ave(session,name, FUN = max)>session))

        name session retained
1  Sen Tom       115        1
2  Sen Tom       116        1
3  Sen Tom       117        0
4  Sen Jack      115        0
5  Sen Jill      116        1
6  Sen Jill      117        0
7  Sen Dave      116        1
8  Sen Dave      117        0
```

in tidyverse

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
df %>%
   mutate(retained = +(max(session) > session), .by = name)

        name session retained
1  Sen Tom       115        1
2  Sen Tom       116        1
3  Sen Tom       117        0
4  Sen Jack      115        0
5  Sen Jill      116        1
6  Sen Jill      117        0
7  Sen Dave      116        1
8  Sen Dave      117        0
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is by using the `dplyr::lead()` function, which returns the value from next row for a selected variable. For your case:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(retained = lead(session) - session) %>%
  mutate(retained = replace_na(retained, 0))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
# Groups:   name [4]
  name     session retained
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Sen Tom      115        1
2 Sen Tom      116        1
3 Sen Tom      117        0
4 Sen Jack     115        0
5 Sen Jill     116        1
6 Sen Jill     117        0
7 Sen Dave     116        1
8 Sen Dave     117        0
```